# Java Input Output Stream can't read the file

Tags: java, stream, java-io

I really need help with Java io manipulation of Streams. I don't know why this won't show me the contents of the file. I need to be able to view the text in this binary file "Data.abc" If I can view the contents of this file, i need to create a switch case condition to display it's contents per row / column.
Everytime I run the program, it returns some weird letters and characters like � NAme Address�����

Please help. I'm new to manipulation of streams. Thanks.

```
package IO_ReadFile;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  InputStream istream;   // creates an Input Stream and named it "istream"
  OutputStream ostream;  // creates an Output Stream and named it "ostream"
  File inputFile = new File("Data.abc"); //passes file as argument
  int c;
  final int EOF=-1;
  ostream = System.out;
  try
  {
     istream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
     try
     {
        while((c=istream.read()) !=EOF)
           ostream.write(c);
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
     finally
     {
        try
        {
           istream.close();
           ostream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        System.out.println("File did not close");
        }
     }
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     System.exit(1);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Jordan, is your file a text file. Please remember if your file has a specific encoding you need to specific to your streamreader. For example like this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

Comment: looks like you have some unicode chars in your file

Comment: What happens when you open the file in a text editor?

Comment: You've already said it's a *binary* file - but you're trying to print it out as if it's text. What's the source? What's the format? What do "row" and "column" mean in this file format?

Comment: Hi, Acewin. It isn't a text file but it does show a few texts and weird characters. Not very familiar with streams.

Comment: @Jordan if its not a text file, you can hardly expect to represent it textually. All of those ? characters are bytes that are not printable. If you are just trying to print the contents of the file in a human readable format, I would recommend trying to convert each byte to hexadecimal format and printing those.

Comment: @JonSkeet the format is an unknown file extension.abc. I tried opening the file in notepad hoping to see its structure or contents but i get some weird characters so I knew it's a binary type. I just assumed there maybe some rows and columns of how it was typed in the notepad. I've been reading and searching about this for hours. I hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know the file format, you're basically stuck. Open a JPG file in Notepad, and ask yourself how you could *possibly* work out what that meant without knowledge of the format. You should concentrate your efforts on determining what produced that file.